# Is there a way to map GAE user object and Google+ userid

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls), for default authentication using python users API an object will be returned based on user's email. When `user_id()` is called over the object a unique id is returned, which is of course not a Google+ user id.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            user = users.get_current_user()
            if user:
                if users.is_current_user_admin():
                    utype = "Admin"
                else:
                    utype = "Normal" 
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
                self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname() + ' Userid: ' + user.user_id() + ' User Type: ' + utype)
            else:
                self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                ('/', MainPage)
                            ], debug=False)
```

Basically, I need the plus id to retrieve some user details. (via [HTTP GET](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get))

Is there any available package in AppEngine API that can provide me with google plus id for a logged in user's email?

Or should I move on to OAuth 2 for authentication purpose?

I have already completed 50% based on users API, so any help regarding the same will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using their user.email()

To access properties of their Google+ profile you will need to use the Google APIs Client Library for Python https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation

Comment: Thanks @lanGSY. Found a way out from your link :) Currently i am using the way shown in the sample for appengine in **google-api-python-client-samples-1.2**.

Comment: The way I normally achieve that, in addition to using the Google APIs Client Library as @IanGSY mentions, is to create my own User model and store there the associated Google+ ID, email address and other profile data. Then you can query your datastore by the ID or by the email address and get all the information. Also, I believe you are required to use OAuth2 (or Google+ sign in) in order to use the G+ client library.

Comment: Yes.. i had to. And like you said, made a custom model and kept the method's name identical to avoid xtra overhead :D