# Is it possible to use the Google account user ID to retrieve a Google+ profile?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

The Google+ platform has a API for retrieving Google+ profiles by ID, documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get).

The problem is I am using Google Cloud Endpoint with its built in authentication which returns the authenticated user as a `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` object, documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User). The `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` user ID is not the same as the Google+ Profile user ID. Quite unfortunate.

What I am looking for is a work around. A way to either recieve the Google+ profile user ID with Google Cloud Endpoint's built in authentication, or use the Google account user ID to get a users corresponding Google+ profile ID.

Comment: Are you using this in a Google Apps Domain? or your cloud endpoint is open for all Google accounts?

Comment: @omerio All accounts.

Comment: Perhaps a dupe of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052790/is-there-a-way-to-map-gae-user-object-and-google-userid

Comment: @SillyWilly The question you referenced is worded such that storing the Google+ profile along side the Google Account is a suitable solution. I am trying to see if there is a way to get the Google+ profile of any user with just knowing their basic Google account info, such as email and account ID. The whole idea is to avoid having to store additional Google+ data.